# nginx slow response after 500 users online

Tags: performance, nginx

I have a file download site, where I use nginx to deliver the files and apache for web part.
However as soon as I hit around 500 users online and 1500Mbit/s, Nginx responses get delayed with 10 to 60 seconds. Once connection established everything works as expected.

Apache have no issues on browse side, HDDs are only 50% util, IOwait is 3, bandwidth is 70% saturated, CPU is 5%. I really don't understand why is this happening, I get no errors in nginx logs.

Comment: what does your nginx config look like (and specifically, what do you have your worker_processes, worker_connections set to, do you have any limit_conn, limit_req, limit_rate directives? ...)

Comment: I only have limit rate and limit_rate_after so that moov part of videos are not delayed, the server is for video playback/download